# Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant for Office 365 - does not install

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

I am Using Windows 10, 64 Bit

I'm subscribed to Office 365

I am the administrator

I am having issues with my Outlook.

I have downloaded application "SetupProd.exe" from my Microsoft account (https://portal.office.com/account/#toolsaddins)

> Microsoft Support and Recovery Assistant for Office 365
>
> Get help troubleshooting and fixing problems you might run into using Outlook or Office 365.

But when I try to install it, as I get the following:

"Application Install - Security Warning"

"Your administration has blocked this application because it potentially poses a security risk to your computer"

From "outlookdiagnostics.asureedge.net"

Publisher is "Microsoft Corporation"

[image]

How can I install this tool?

I have found a similar question on Microsoft portal without answers from a year ago. (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/microsoft-support-and-recovery-assistant-for/bd2072c9-4e5b-41ee-a556-6817a230bafd). This question is blocked there.

Comment: Is this a business subscription? or a personal subscription?

Comment: Have you unblocked the file?  You can find the option within the Properties of the file.

Comment: what is the property name?

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the security settings for ClickOnce applications to default should resolve the issue:

[Unable to Install ClickOnce Application due to Security Settings (Windows 10)](https://superuser.com/questions/1252575/unable-to-install-clickonce-application-due-to-security-settings-windows-10)

The location of the appropriate registry keys are at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\.NETFramework\Security\TrustManager\PromptingLevel`
[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-configure-the-clickonce-trust-prompt-behavior?view=vs-2022&tabs=csharp)

Once found, enable everything but `UntrustedSites`. Personally had this issue and this is what resolved it.